# Use method in template, out of instance vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

This is warning when i click on go to contact in tab about: "Property or method "switchTo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in component )."

How do I fix this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentPage: 'home',
  },
  methods: {
     switchTo: function(page) {
            this.currentPage = page;
     }
  },
  components: {
    home: {
      template: `#home`,
     },
    about: {
      template: `#about`,  
    },
    contact: {
      template: '#contact'

    }
  }
})
```

```css
.navigation {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

input, label, button {
  display: block
}

input, textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" @click="switchTo('home')">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" @click="switchTo('about')">About</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="pages">
    <keep-alive>
      <component v-bind:is="currentPage">
      </component>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="home">
<p>home</p>
</template>

<template id="about">
<p>about <a href="#contact" @click="switchTo('contact')">go to contact</a></p>

</template>

<template id="contact">
<p>contact</p>
</template>
```

Comment: It's because the `switchTo()`method is only defined into the root Vue instance, that hold child components, and It's not available into the child component by default.

Comment: I understood this, but i would like to understand if there is a way to not change the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `about` template to this

```
<template id="about">
    <p>about <a href="#contact" @click="$root.switchTo('contact')">go to contact</a></p>
</template>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentPage: 'home',
  },
  methods: {
     switchTo: function(page) {
            this.currentPage = page;
     }
  },
  components: {
    home: {
      template: `#home`,
     },
    about: {
      template: `#about`,  
    },
    contact: {
      template: '#contact'

    }
  }
})
```

```css
.navigation {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

input, label, button {
  display: block
}

input, textarea {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home" @click="switchTo('home')">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about" @click="switchTo('about')">About</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="pages">
    <keep-alive>
      <component v-bind:is="currentPage">
      </component>
    </keep-alive>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="home">
<p>home</p>
</template>

<template id="about">
<p>about <a href="#contact" @click="$root.switchTo('contact')">go to contact</a></p>

</template>

<template id="contact">
<p>contact</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I already solved a problem like this in this question: [Calling methods in Vue build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884396/calling-methods-in-vue-build/41891774#41891774)

It's not the same problem so it's not a repeated question, but the answer is the same:

In the created hook, add the component to window.componentInstance like this:

```
methods: {
  foo () {
    console.log('bar')
  }
}, 
created () {
  window.componentInstance = this
}
```

Then you can call the method anywhere like this:

```
window.componentInstance.foo()
```